# @font_face problem

Tags: css, fonts, types, font-face

This problem with calling up the font that has been declared at the start of the CSS has been bugging me for a day. I've checked many resources and the code seems to be ok, but maybe i'm missing something. I've put in the @font face and tried to use it in my h1 header but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance guys.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Photoblog</TITLE>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>  
</HEAD>
<BODY>



<div id="container">  

<header>
    <H1>Howard Tang</H1>
</header>

</div>

<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id='container'>

    <aside>
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    <p>Hello here is some placeholder text.Hello here is some placeholder text.Hello here is some placeholder text.</p>
    </aside>

    <article>
    <h2>Welcome:</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus et eros justo, quis consectetur arcu. 
    Etiam vel orci massa, vel vestibulum ante. Nam posuere luctus iaculis. In id augue augue. 
    Integer vel massa purus, sit amet tincidunt sapien. Integer sit amet adipiscing risus. 
    Praesent rhoncus mauris mattis justo mattis eget egestas augue interdum. Curabitur tempus accumsan lacus 
    id accumsan. Nulla fermentum, purus a tempus tristique, diam nibh porttitor felis, et aliquet nunc nisl ac 
    turpis. </p>    
    <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="Angry face" class="resize"/>
    </article>

    <article>
    <h2>First Impressions</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus et eros justo, quis consectetur arcu. 
    Etiam vel orci massa, vel vestibulum ante. Nam posuere luctus iaculis. In id augue augue. 
    Integer vel massa purus, sit amet tincidunt sapien. Integer sit amet adipiscing risus. 
    Praesent rhoncus mauris mattis justo mattis eget egestas augue interdum. Curabitur tempus accumsan lacus 
    id accumsan. Nulla fermentum, purus a tempus tristique, diam nibh porttitor felis, et aliquet nunc nisl ac 
    turpis. </p>    
    <img src="pic2.jpg" alt="Angry face" />

    </article>

    <article>
    <h2>Bro</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus et eros justo, quis consectetur arcu. 
    Etiam vel orci massa, vel vestibulum ante. Nam posuere luctus iaculis. In id augue augue. 
    Integer vel massa purus, sit amet tincidunt sapien. Integer sit amet adipiscing risus. 
    Praesent rhoncus mauris mattis justo mattis eget egestas augue interdum. Curabitur tempus accumsan lacus 
    id accumsan. Nulla fermentum, purus a tempus tristique, diam nibh porttitor felis, et aliquet nunc nisl ac 
    turpis. </p>
    <img src="pic3.gif" alt="Angry face" />
    </article>

<footer>
    <p>By Howard Tang</p>
    </footer>

</div>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Blackout';
    src: url('fonts/Blackout2.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


body {
background-color:#F2E9E1;
color : #111111;
font-family : "Arial", "helvetica", sans-serif;
font-size : 11pt;
}

header h1 {
background-color: #1C140D;
color: #ffffff;
display:block;
height: 80px;
width: 900px;
text-align : left;
line-height: 80px ;
font-size: 60px;
font-family:'Blackout',Sans-Serif;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

nav ul {

list-style : none;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
margin: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
text-align : center;
}

nav ul li {
color : #111111;
margin: 0px;
display : block;
}

nav {
width:1900px;
align:center;
background-color:#F2E9E1;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

nav a {
color : #111111;
}

nav ul li {
display : inline;
}

article {
background-color: #CBE86B;
float: left;
padding: 20px 20px 40px;
width: 560px;
height: 560px;
}

article img {
float: left;
height : 350px;
width : 550px;
}

aside {
    background-color: #1C140D;
    color: #CBE86B;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 1840px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#container {
width : 900px;
margin : 0 auto;
}

footer  {
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? For example, IE doesn't support .ttf as far as I recall.

Comment: Try using fontsquirrel's @font-face generator script. They do the autohinting, GASP-table fitting, scaling, and wrapping for you -- the output is a bunch of files that, in combination, work on most browsers. Blackout has a prepackaged kit here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontfacekit/Blackout

Comment: I'm testing in Firefox, and have already tried using the fontsquirrel package. What was interesting was that the demo worked but when I implemented it into my page it didn't so there is something wrong with the code.

Comment: @sebastian_k: Font Squirrel! Good to see it being recommended.

Comment: Have you tried implementing your page into the demo step by step, instead of implementing the demo into your page? Maybe that way you'll see what causes the problem :)

Comment: This sounds like a smart idea and I will have a go in a while. Thanks for the help sebastian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that font face src pathing is relative to the stylesheet file. So my fonts were actually in the wrong folder, which meant the code was ok but it was a simple pathing error.

I figured it out after a couple of days of frustration and will not be making this simple mistake again, thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser support different type of font ( http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/ ):

- Internet Explorer only supports EOT
- Mozilla browsers support OTF and TTF
- Safari and Opera support OTF, TTF and SVG
- Chrome supports TTF and SVG.
  so your css should look like this:

  @font-face {

  ```
  font-family: 'Blackout';
  src: url('/Resources/fonts/Blacout2.eot');
  src: url('fonts/Blacout2.ttf'), url('fonts/Blacout2.woff'), url('fonts/Blacout2.svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  ```

  }

Comment: Hello kleinohad, I forgot to mention that I was already aware of this, and have tried different combos and cross browser tested. The problem is something other than the browser client not supporting ttf (mainly using Firefox). I appreciate that the code should cover all the types and my code looked like that before but I removed them all but the ttf for testing purposes.

Comment: try to add / src: url('/fonts/Blacout2.ttf'); test with firebug to see if the ttf file is called

Comment: Right I tested in Firebug and it seems to recognise to call for Blackout as it does not inherit from the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is that you have NoScript (or similar) installed? It's known to block web fonts unless you allow them.

Comment: Just opened up a webfont demo page and no problems there. It is isolated to my page.

Comment: Could just be a simple typo in the filepath? I notice this is missing a 'k' for example: `fonts/Blacout2.ttf`

Comment: Well observed, and there was a path error, however I've changed it around a few times which is the reason for this. Changed it so the pathing is now correct and still the same error.

Comment: Hmmm. Clutching at straws now, but are you using XHTML? In which case <H1> needs to be <h1>

Comment: I already changed the capitalised H and yes I know this is a bizarre problem. Everything seems like it should work but it just doesn't want to. I'm about to test in firebug as kleinohad has suggested